# How to put Google Map in sliding drawer

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

Let's say I have an activity which is called Main, and in this activity I                                      have a sliding drawer . 
I wonder if instead of putting an image in the sliding drawer maybe I could put the map, so when I slide out the drawer I can use the map.
Is it possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display anything you want in the drawer, the format is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout id="container />
    <!-- ListView, Fragment etc -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for me info.